# Convert BED file to WIG file

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bed

Do you know any way to convert easily (either by R, or with other program) a BED file to WIG?

Can you give me some guidelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [rtracklayer](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/rtracklayer.html) package and specifically at the following man pages:

```
 ?import
 ?export
```

Comment: thank you...do you know if there is way to convert a bedgraph to bed??? how this can be done?

Comment: For bioinformatics-related questions I suggest you to post on http://www.biostars.org/ . For example this question http://www.biostars.org/post/show/10141/bedgraph-to-bed/ .

Answer (score 2):

Here is a specific example of how I would convert `.bed` to `.wig`. As @Paolo implied, it's a straight-forward procedure:

```
library(rtracklayer) #bioconductor

bed_loaded <- import(con="~/Downloads/my_bed.bed.gz", format="bed") #no need to unzip .gz
# bed_loaded <- import.bed(con="~/Downloads/my_bed.bed") #if you unzip 

export.wig(object=bed_loaded, con="~/Downloads/bed2wig.wig")
```

Note that you `import` and `export` both have methods (wig, bed, bigwig or bw, etc.). You may directly use them without specifying the method but specifying `format` argument.

This [GitHub tutorial](http://kasperdanielhansen.github.io/genbioconductor/html/rtracklayer_Import.html#other-file-formats) will be helpful.